# How to pass array to method

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

It's probably a stupid question, but anyway.
My problem is that I can't pass uninitialized array, but I don't know if my array need to hold 5 or 30000 elements, eg. so it will be a waist of memory to initialize big array.

Should I use `List<T>` instead, or?
I've noticed people tend to return array instead of list, which is mutable, and therefore much more convenient, so there must be a performance issue with lists. Is that so?

Comment: What is the use case for the array? Do you set it once, or add and remove elements consistently?

Comment: Can you share your code and what you're trying to do?

Comment: once. something like that: void ListAllDotNetAssemblies(out string[] exe32, out string[] exe64, out string[] dll32, out string[] dll64, string dir = "")

Comment: Edit your question and past your code.

Comment: You can pass un-initialized values in regards to `out` parameters. If you do `string[] arr; foo(out arr);` it will compile and you can do what you need to do with the array in `foo`. So I'm still not sure what you're trying to do or what the problem is.

Comment: Arrays are really only useful if you *do* know the amount of elements you have. `I've noticed people tend to return array` - I disagree, Lists are far more common in C# than arrays. In any case, `List` uses an array internally, and automatically manages resizing the array for you. Go with a list unless you have a proven issue with memory due to using `List` instead of an array.

Comment: Yes, I can, but I missed the out keyword, so it gaved me the "unassigned local variable" error. My bad, post it as answer, I guess...

Comment: The answer depends very much on whether you can tell how many elements your data will have when you allocate the data structure. If you e.g. iterate a directory and add file names one by one, a list is your buddy. If you want to return the 50 biggest files on your disk, you can as well define an array of 50 strings right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make it into an 'out' parameter and all should be well:

```
private void x()
{
    string sTestFile = "this is a test";   
    string[] TestFileWords;

    FixConcatString(sTestFile, out TestFileWords);
}


private void FixConcatString(string splayfile, **out** string[] sWordArray)
{
    char[] charSeparators = new char[] { '-' };
    splayfile = splayfile.ToLower();
    splayfile = splayfile.Replace(@"\", " ");

    sWordArray =  splayfile.Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

Comment: Why not just *return* the array: `private String[] FixConcatString(string splayfile) {...}` which is more natural than using `out` parameter?

Comment: In addition to @DmitryBychenko's comment, what is the point of `charSeparators` being an array with only a single element, instead of just using an individual `char` variable?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko.. you dont need to.. and this is just an example... when you fill the out variable, after the function ends, u will get that value..